# Why Qt Entity type does not support states property?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt3d

Does anyone have an explanation on why [Qt3D](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-index.html) [Entity](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-core-entity.html) type does not have support for a `states` property as [Item](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#states-prop) does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`states` is specific to `Item`s which are 2D visual elements.

`Entity`s are 3D visual elements and not part of the QML 2D visual family so they are designed and work differently. Sounds like you may want to contact the Qt folks and make a feature request to add `state` functionality to `Entity`s.

In the meantime, you might be able to create and attach an invisible `Item` to your entities and just use it for its state management abilities to drive visual changes on your Entity.